# How to form a PHP tree menu?

Tags: php, database, menu, path, tree

I have some paths stored in my db as: They are unsorted and can be any length.

--------Paths--------

> C:/devices/data1
>
> C:/devices/data1/application2
>
> C:/devices/data1/application1
>
> C:/devices/data2/application3
>
> C:/devices/data2/application2
>
> C:/devices/data2/application1
>
> C:/devices/data1/application3

I need to form a menu as below:

```
C > devices > data1> application1 
                     application2 
                     application3 
              data2> application1 
                     application2 
                     application3
```

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Wish for some quick responses. Thanks!

Ulvund's solution works for me but now I need to generate the links to the href tags:

I tried the following:

http://www.pbalan01.0fees.net/god1.php

Please help me remove the extra node: it currently generates...

```
C:/devices/data1
           data1/application1
                 application2
                 application3
           data2
           data2/application1
                 application2
                 application3
```

Comment: Is changing the DB structure an option ?

Comment: Yo Prashant I edited my solution to reflect your wish for menu styling (look at the bottom)

Comment: teresko, I dont think changing the db is an option. Now I am good with Ulvund's solution but only thing is I need to generate the links for <a href> tags

Answer (score 3):

```
$paths[] = "C:/devices/data1";
$paths[] = "C:/devices/data1/application2";
$paths[] = "C:/devices/data1/application1";
$paths[] = "C:/devices/data2/application3";
$paths[] = "C:/devices/data2/application2";
$paths[] = "C:/devices/data2/application1";
$paths[] = "C:/devices/data1/application3";


function to_tree(&$multifruit, $fruit) {
    if (count($fruit)>2) {
        $shifted = array_shift($fruit);
        to_tree($multifruit[$shifted], $fruit);
        return $multifruit;
    } else {
        return $multifruit[$fruit[0]][] = $fruit[1];
    }   
}   

sort($paths);
foreach($paths as $path) {
   $path = explode("/",$path);
   to_tree($multifruit, $path);
}   

print_r($multifruit);
/* Result
Array
(
    [C:] => Array
        (
            [devices] => Array
                (
                    [0] => data1
                    [data1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => application1
                            [1] => application2
                            [2] => application3
                        )

                    [data2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => application1
                            [1] => application2
                            [2] => application3
                        )

                )

        )

)


*/
```

**EDIT**:

To have your full desired result (or the closest you will get with my help): Use the following code: http://hpaste.org/54546

See a sample on http://redditlist.com/test2.php

**EDIT 3**:

http://redditlist.com/test3.php

http://hpaste.org/54599

Comment: Hi Ulvund,
Many thanks for your early reply. Could you tell me the logic of this function? I am totally lost with this problem.
Also I would appreciate if you could tell me how it performs sort?

Comment: To sort: Just add **ksort($paths);** as i just did in the edit :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I would wanna ask a question further:

I need to print each level in like here:

http://www.pbalan01.0fees.net/test2.html

Could you tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi Ulvund,
I think your solution works for only the paths that are sorted in an array by its length... ???

Comment: ksort($paths) is invalid, you must use sort() because you are sorting values and not keys of the array...

Comment: OK I've changed the solution to using **sort**

Comment: Updated the example to work like http://pbalan01.0fees.net/test2.html

Comment: Ulvund, Don't know how can I thank you more for this solution dude.. You saved my life. Its the perfect solution.
One last question though, how can I generate paths to those href tags, so that when I click them, I can go to that specific directory.

For instance:

If I click on application1 under on data1:
I am redirected to the path ---

C:\devices\data\application1

Comment: Hi Ulvund, could you please help with generating the path links for those href tags..

Comment: @ulvund, please help a bit more with generating the links to the href tags as mentioned above in my command, I tried a bit of code, which produces a wrong link and sometimes like for hover on 'devices', does not produce a correct link!

Comment: @Ulvund
I am trying to get the href links but am not able to get them correct, please help!!

Thanks

Comment: @Ulvund: Many thanks, I was so frustrated with it.. You made it work, awesome!!

Comment: @ulvund Hi, I am looking for an answer to the above question again. I need to fix the above code for creating menus with items that appear only once in the menu.
For eg: C:
        C:/devices/data1
        C:/devices
Currently the menu shows devices twice.. once as a value and once as an array. I need to remove the value if its a key to another array. Please help

Comment: I already answered your original question 3 times and you have accepted it many times.

Comment: @Prashant: Please ask a new question if you have one.

Comment: @Will: I have posted the new question already!

Comment: @ulvund: I understand you answered, I understand, I accepted. But project leader has changed priorities, and I am stuck. If you could just help me with this. I think, you understand what to modify. So I turned back to you...

Comment: @Prashant I find it incredibly offensive that you demand me to do your work because I helped you in the past

Comment: @ulvund: I am really sorry, but I never meant it to be this way. Just thought if you could help me.. I would do it by myself. I am sorry for all the trouble and hurting your emotions.

Answer (score 1):

## CODE

```
<?php

$rows = array(
    'C:/devices/data1',
    'C:/devices/data1/application2',
    'C:/devices/data1/application1',
    'C:/devices/data2/application3',
    'C:/devices/data2/application2',
    'C:/devices/data2/application1',
    'C:/devices/data1/application3',
);
sort($rows);

$sorted = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    eval('$sorted["' . implode('"]["', explode('/', $row)) . '"] = array();');
}
print_r($sorted);

?>
```

## OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [C:] => Array
        (
            [devices] => Array
                (
                    [data1] => Array
                        (
                            [application1] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [application2] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [application3] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                    [data2] => Array
                        (
                            [application1] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [application2] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [application3] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Glavic, perfect solution... I am new to PHP, I would be pleased to know the logic of the solution.

Comment: Galvic sort data with mysql, how? any db query if you could suggest.

Comment: Hi Glavic,

Thanks a lot. I would wanna ask a question further: I need to print each level in like here: pbalan01.0fees.net/test2.html Could you tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi Galvic,
I think your solution works for only the paths that are sorted in an array by its length... ???
I am facing some problems when I change the paths to different values..

Comment: True, it was not ok if you had unsorted paths. I edited and fixed that with simple if. It should work now. Again: you dont need sorting if you select data from database. You can even sort array of paths before calling my loop, easy fix. If you fix, that database result will be sorted, you can then remove 2 lines in foreach loop (it can be only one)...

Comment: Glavic, Thanks for your support too. Your solution was also near perfect, however Ulvund worked out the way I wanted it. Thank you..